# Visual Studio 2015 error compiling C++ wizard project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

When I use *Visual Studio 2015*, an error at compile time is raised when I try to create a new *Win32 C++ project*. I follow the following steps:

- File -> New -> Project... -> Win32 Project
- I select the name of my project, press Ok button.
  Next
- I select:
  Windows Application
- Finish

During the build time of the project the reported errors are:

```
cannot open source file "string.h"
cannot open source file "ctype.h"
...
```

Comment: What is the code you're trying to compile. Post a [MCVE] please. Otherwise its impossible to diagnose your problem.

Comment: The code was any code created by the Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fount a solution.

In Project -> myproject properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories, I add the directory of ucrt, that belong to Windows Kits, in the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10150\ucrt
```

Ant in In Project -> myproject properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories add:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10150\ucrt\x86
```

And thats all.